# Problem compiling boost 1_46_1 with Intel Compiler 12 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, intel

When compiling boost filesystem (1_46_1) with Intel 12 Release 4, and Visual Studio 10, I get this error:

```
   [cc] F:/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp(126): error: expected either a definition or a tag name
   [cc]     BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_START(copy_option)
   [cc]     ^
```

It works fine when compiling for Visual Studio 2008 (and 2005).

Although compiled with custom ant build scripts, bjam fails for the same reason.

Any hints for fixing this are greatly appreciated. We have a local copy of boost so we can make modifications to it.

Comment: Well, does it compile successfully with bjam?

Comment: I will try now (give me a while, I don't get on well with bjam!) My instinct is that it will fail with bjam too. It works with our ant script for 2005 and 2008 without hitch. (we use ant so we can easily keep our project & our boost libs compiled with the same compiler args, like wchar_t.) I just came across this through google... http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Intel-12-c-compiler-issues-td3523569.html which seems related.

Comment: Yes, it is broken with bjam too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in boost 1_46_1 - [#5661](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5661). You can fix it by:

- Upgrading to [boost 1_47_0](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_47_0.html) (just released) which should fix it according to ticket 5661.

Or

- Stick with boost 1_46_1 and pass /Qstd=c++0x as a compiler option.

Answer (score 0):

That macro is defined in `boost/detail/scoped_enum_emulation.hpp`.  Modify your compiler options to output preprocessed source, and dig through it to find out why that's not being included properly.  Perhaps the Ant script is not setting the compiler version correctly for `boost/config.hpp`.

Comment: Can you offer a bit of guidance here. I've compiled with /P which has given me a bunch of 'filename.i' intermediaries, about 250000 lines long, mostly filled with whitespace. What should I look for in them? Sorry this is such a vague question, but I'm really unsure where to start!

Comment: Edit the file and search for BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_START. Probably the line you noted in the q will be the first occurrence.  Then, you have to work out why scoped_enum_emulation.hpp is not being included.  There's no shortcut here.  Once this is sorted out, get BJam working and use that as a stable reference for your future work (or just stop this Ant usage).

Comment: Ok, "BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_START" isn't a token in operations.i, but   enum class copy_option
    {none, fail_if_exists = none, overwrite_if_exists}; is - so it is being expanded I think?

Comment: Does the Intel compiler support this syntax?  Perhaps you need to define `BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS` to get this compiled.

Comment: Defining `BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS` gets me a new warning (and the same compile error.) `[cc] F:/boost/config/compiler/common_edg.hpp(88): warning #47: incompatible redefinition of macro "BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS".` The solution is near though! When I change `scoped_enum_emulation.hpp` to unconditionally use namespaced enums, the code compiles fine. Now the only problem left is why the macro isn't following the correct path...

Comment: v strange.  Did you check whether bjam builds this with your Intel toolchain?  Could just be a bug in the headers, though I find that unlikely.

Comment: With bjam and unmodified boost, it fails in the same way as our ant setup. If I alter `scoped_enum_emulation.hpp` to unconditionally use namespaced enums, bjam succeeds. I'm digging through the boost headers a bit now...

Comment: Found it! In boost/config/compiler/intel.hpp, BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS is undefed. (line 212) Commenting this out results in successful compilation!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a work-round. Might be worth communicating your experience back in Boost forums.

Comment: I agree completely and tried to this morning! However I have no idea where the boost forums are, I know they have mailing lists, but it's not clear where I would communicate there. Where would you recommend providing feedback?

Comment: I would try here.  Just describe the issue and see what happens. http://www.boost.org/community/groups.html#users